# AJAX and back button

Tags: javascript, ajax, history

How can I save history with AJAX just how github or google+ do. I use jQuery and I do not want to use some kind of hack like the # and #! tricks, because if I do, I'll need to change my whole project and make my life much more complicated?

Answer (score 5):

Github and Google+ are using [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method).

You can change the current url like this:

```
history.pushState(null, null, '/the-new-url');
```

This is supported by Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari; not IE.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method

Answer (score 5):

There are basically two options when it comes to AJAX and history.

1. The # method (which isn't a hack btw). Since you don't want that one you only have option 2 left.
2. Use PushState. This is what Facebook, GitHub and a few others use. It's not supported by all browsers though and if you want complete cross-browser compatibility you will have to use a system which can degrade to option 1.

A very simple way to implement this is Backbone.js Router class.

Comment: The # method is very much a hack. The point of fragment identifiers is to link to specific parts of a document, not to tell JavaScript which URLs to get data from to populate parts of the page via Ajax.

Comment: Well, yes, if we are really picky and strict, that was the original intended use, but since it's so widely supported and used, I would more like to call it a "clever use of mechanics" than a "hack" which I think sound way too negative.

Comment: I think that 'hack' does [not sound negative enough](http://blog.benward.me/post/3231388630). In this context, the term means "Using something for other than its intended purpose", which fits this exactlyl

Answer (score 1):

There is [a simple jQuery hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) that is designed to solve this specific problem.

I haven't used it; I don't know how it keeps track of the url history.