# Which solution is best when the browser back button is hit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

I have an application and the problem I have is with the back brower buttons, if the user cliks on a back browser, then it would mess things up in the application.

So I want to do either 2 things:

Solution 1: I have found a site where it shows the javascript code for disabling back buttons on all browsers. Obviously you need javascript enabled for this to work but my application won't work very well without javascript anyway so this won't be a problem (I include a warning in each page in my application stating javascript must be enabled in order to use the app)

Solution 2: IF the user does click on the back button at any time, then it will navigate the user to the safety.php page where on this page it will inform the user that they can't use the browser back button, then it will destroy all of the sessions so that the user is logged out. If they want to use the app again then they will have to login again and use the app from the beginning.

My question is that out of both solutions, which one would be better to use? My application is where a teacher creates an online assessment, creating the assessments detials (start time/ duration date etc) and creating the  questions and answers for each assesment (could be single or multiple assessments)

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX and back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174835/ajax-and-back-button)

Comment: I'd hate to use an application that doesn't let me use the back button. Being able to go back is a basic feature of the web and gives users a feeling of safety. Please don't take that away from them.

Comment: What do you mean by going back messed up the application?

Comment: What does it mess exactly when pushing the back button? Maybe that can be fixed.

Comment: @Guy lets say that the teacher is creating 3 assessments for example. They create assessment 1's questions and answers and then submit the page, this will insert all of the data into the database and will navigate the teacher to then next assessment (assessment 2), now if the teacher pressess the back button, then they could potentially go back to assessment 1, if they fill in the questins and answers again for assessmnet 1, then it means they will have both sets of questions and answers for assessment 1. This will mess things up especially in the database with possible duplicates

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: So this isn't a problem with the back button, it's a problem with the same form being filled in twice. Use a one time token in a hidden field and ignore subsequent updates. And remember to load the values the user entered back in if they refresh. If you're paranoid, you might even add some JS that checks if the form has already been submitted if the user goes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the back button is generally poor usability practice. Your best bet is to manipulate the history object (search pushState if you're not familiar with these methods) so that hitting the back button would return them to a page outside your experience, or however you're accomplishing "Solution 2", but warn them that they are leaving the "logged in" section before they actually leave the page, so that they can choose to stay, using `confirm()` or a custom pop-up.

Comment: I like the idea of shoiwng and confirmation box o that the user knows that if they press the back button, they will be informed in the confirmation that if they press the back button that they will be logged out and lose all of their progress, if they press cancel then they remain on the page. Do you think it is better to give the teacher an option to either confirm if they want to leave or not, or do you think it will be better to simply display an alert, if the teacher clicks on the back button then display an alert stating back button can't be used now and remain user on the current page?

Comment: You really want them to give them that choice. Maybe they accidentally clicked the back button, or didn't know they shouldn't: they would just lose all their progress if you kicked them out without warning. A confirmation box gives them a chance to go "oh crap that's not what I wanted to do!" and cancel.

Comment: Ok I will do it the way you have stated.Very helpful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

use javascript in the first place to prevent adding the location to the history list.
catch the **onclick** event of the proper link, and use `document.location.replace("next_page.html");`
so this way, when a user clicks the back button he would leave your site, rather then going back and messing up your app.

also: you can catch the **unload** event of the page where the user presses back button, so that you can confirm the user for exiting.

Comment: that would be window.location.replace()

Comment: @alfred can you read comment I posted in other answer, and tell me if you think it is better to cnfirm or alert?